# Delay localhost vs reality

Tags: testing, web, delay

I know delay Can be caused by alot of different things such as location internet speed ect ect. But if you are a Web developer who is building content heavy webpages how dó you estimat delay? And how does the delay on localhost compare to reality?

Comment: Your question is not really clear: Do you mean how to simulate delay ? or how to measure user connect speed ?

Comment: How to messire content loading speed like when dó you know that you have too much content